# Derive the approximation $\int_{a+h}^a f(x)\;dx =\frac{h}{2}[f(a) + f(a + h)] + \frac{h^2}{12} [f_0(a) − f_0(a + h)] + O(h^5)$

Tags: numerical-methods

Let $f$ be a smooth function. Derive the approximation
$\int_{a+h}^a
f(x)\;dx =\frac{h}{2}[f(a) + f(a + h)] + \frac{h^2}{12}
[f_0(a) − f_0(a + h)] + O(h^5)$

Comment: What is $f_0$? What have you tried so far? Are you sure about $O(h^5)$ ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to derive the error bound for the trapezoid (or Simpson's) method. This kind of exercises is usually solved by expanding $f$ as its Taylor polynomial plus some for of the remainder (like the integral remainder), i.e. by considering $\int_{0}^{h}(h-x)^k (f(x)-f(0))\,dx$. Nevertheless, you should improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the Hermite interpolating polynomial of order 3, and letting $z_0=z_1=a$ and $z_2=z_3=a+h$
\begin{align*}
H_3(x) = &f[z_0]+f[z_0,z_1](x-z_0) + f[z_0,z_1,z_2](x-z_0)(x-z_1) \\
&+ f[z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3](x-z_0)(x-z_1)(x-z_2)\\=&f(a)+f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)}{h}(x-a)^2 +\\ &\frac{f'(a+h)+f'(a)-2\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}{h^2}(x-a)^2(x-(a+h))
\end{align*}

Thus $\int_{a+h}^a
f(x)\;dx \approx H_3(x) = \frac{h}{2}[f(a) + f(a + h)] + \frac{h^2}{12}
[f_(a) − f_(a + h)]$

We note the error term is $\int_{a+h}^a
f(x)-H_3(x)\;dx = \int_{a+h}^a
\frac{f^{(4)}(\epsilon(x))}{4!}(x-a)^2(x-(a+h))^2\;dx $

We note that since within $[a,a+h], |x-a| \text{ and } |x-(a+h)|$ is less than $h$, the error is (by comparison test) not more than

$K\int_{a+h}^a
h^4\;dx = Kh^5$, for some constants $h,K$, which is $O(h^5)$, as required.